# JAXB - using inheritence for dynamic tag names

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

Im trying to marshall an XML into a class heiarchy, using JAXB - and i want the heiarchy to use inheritence in a generic way. I will explain better:

I have the following XML:

```
<Country name="USA">
    <City name="NewYork">
      <Street name="Something"/>
      <Street name="Something2"/>
    </City>
    <City name="LosAngeles">
       <Street name="Something"/>
       <Street name="Something2"/>
    </City>
<Country>
<Country .....>
   <.....>
    <.....
</Country>
```

etc. where eatch country can have multiple cities and each city can have multiple streets.

I want to create a class called GeneralLocation which will look something like this:

```
 @XmlTransient
    public abstract class GeneralLocation {

        private String name;
        protected List<GeneralLocation> sons;


        @XmlAttribute(name="name")  
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<GeneralLocation> getSons(){
              return this.sons
        }

        public void setSons(List<GeneralLocation> sons){
              this.sons = sons;
        }
    }
```

then create the Country,City, and Street classes to inherite from the GeneralLocation and over ride the getSons method with the correct name for JAXB parsing.

```
public class Country extends GeneralLocation{

        @XmlElement(name="City")
        public List<GeneralLocation> getSons(){
              return this.sons
        }

        public void setSons(List<GeneralLocation> sons){
              this.sons = sons;
        }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of variations on this basic code, none of them do the work. i'm not adding any specific one i did because they all throw verious Exceptions that seems to indicate i am really not on the right path, so i decided to add this basic skeleton and hope for any pointers from you guys...

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation for your use case.

### Java Model

**GeneralLocation**

You can use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on the `sons` property.  The name of the element in the XML will be based on the root element associated with the subclass of the object referenced.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlSeeAlso({Country.class, City.class, Street.class})
public abstract class GeneralLocation {

    private String name;
    protected List<GeneralLocation> sons;

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<GeneralLocation> getSons(){
        return this.sons;
    }

    public void setSons(List<GeneralLocation> sons){
        this.sons = sons;
    }

}
```

**Country**

The subclasses don't need to override the `sons` property.  The only thing they need to have is the `@XmlRootElement` annotation that will be used by the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on `GeneralLocation` to derive the element name.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Country")
public class Country extends GeneralLocation {
}
```

**City**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="City")
public class City extends GeneralLocation {
}
```

**Street**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Street")
public class Street extends GeneralLocation {
}
```

### Demo Code

Below is some example code that unmarshals the XML to objects, and then marshals it back to XML again.  Note that since we used the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the `GeneralLocation` class we don't need to specify all the subclasses when we bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(GeneralLocation.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        GeneralLocation result = (GeneralLocation) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

The XML in your question wasn't valid since you didn't have just one root element, so for my answer I chose to use just a single country.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Country name="USA">
    <City name="NewYork">
        <Street name="Something"/>
        <Street name="Something2"/>
    </City>
    <City name="LosAngeles">
        <Street name="Something"/>
        <Street name="Something2"/>
    </City>
</Country>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not as generic as you would like but I figured it might help you understand why you received various Exception (I myself stumbled upon many trying to find a solution).

First I used the following XML as test (I assume you omitted to root element):

```
<root>
    <Country name="USA">
        <City name="NewYork">
            <Street name="Something" />
            <Street name="Something2" />
        </City>
        <City name="LosAngeles">
            <Street name="Something" />
            <Street name="Something2" />
        </City>
    </Country>
    <Country name="France">
        <City name="Paris">
            <Street name="Champs-Elysees" />
            <Street name="La sante" />
        </City>
    </Country>
</root>
```

As for the classes themselves, I kept the same structure as yours, Country, City and Street inherits from GeneralLocation. However, I removed the list of children from GeneralLocation and instead each class (except Street) holds a List with the proper children type (City inside Country for instance).
It seems to fit best your goals since your original structure allow Street to have City or Country as children, which aside of the natural contradiction could cause issue if you want to marshall from a class model to XML. Therefore I ended with the following classes:

```
public abstract class GeneralLocation {

    protected String name;

    public GeneralLocation() {
        name = "";
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I got rid of the @XmlTransient annotation since it is not necessary in my experience.

```
@XmlType
public class Street extends GeneralLocation {

    public Street() {
   }
```

}

Street has no children and thus is prevented from holding cities or countries as children. I also just realized you didn't the @XmlType annotation on top of the class definition, this might a cause of parsing error here.

```
@XmlType
public class City extends GeneralLocation {

    private List<Street> streets;

    public City() {
        streets = new LinkedList<Street>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Street")
    public List<Street> getStreets() {
        return streets;
    }

}

@XmlType
public class Country extends GeneralLocation{

    private List<City> cities;

    public Country() {
        cities = new LinkedList<City>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name="City")
    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "", name = "root")
public class Root {

    private List<Country> countries;

    public Root() {
        countries = new LinkedList<Country>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Country")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
}
```

City and Country are really similar here, they both hold a list of their respective children (the user can't mess up = security) and JAXB can access the name attribute in the superclass through the annotation (this however depends on your access policy, see below). Finally I put a root class that is tagged with the @XmlRootElement and holds the countries.

Finally, I would recommend that you define the accessor type in your package definition (file package-info.java) to make sure the way JAXB access the data is consistent (only annotations for instance):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) //annotations only
package test;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
```

With that you should be all set to unmarshall your xml :) As a bonus, the main I used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    JAXBContext jaxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller unm = jaxbc.createUnmarshaller();
    File countries = new File("countries.xml");
    Root result = (Root) unm.unmarshal(countries);
}
```

Sadly I couldn't get JAXB to run with the children held by GeneralLocation, I get an UnmarshalException (could not create an instance of GeneralLocation) but I hope this helps anyway. I thinks this a more appropriate way to approach the problem though, it is not as flexible but ensure that the document's structure is consistent.

Also you should check out Blaise Doughan blogs : http://blog.bdoughan.com/ , it contains a lot of useful informations for JAXB developers ;)

Comment: You may be interested in my answer to this question where I use `@XmlElementRef` to map the original model:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27857384/383861

Comment: @Blaise That is indeed a better approach, I read about `@XmlSeeAlso`  but didn't figure out how to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: There isn't much magic to `@XmlSeeAlso` it just tells JAXB to also produce metadata for additional classes (used here because in Java you can't reflectively determine subclasses).  The key point is the use of `@XmlElementRef` and `@XmlRootElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest you a different approach, because I think you use the wrong tool for your problem. When you use [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with this project) instead of data binding, you get a short and general solution that is IMHO not possible with JAXB:

```
public class LocationExample {

    public interface GeneralLocation {
        @XBRead("@name")
        String getName();

        @XBRead("name()")
        String getType();

        @XBRead("./*")
        List<GeneralLocation> getSons();

        @XBRead("/root/Country")
        List<GeneralLocation> getCountries();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
         GeneralLocation location = new XBProjector().io().url("resource://locations.xml").read(GeneralLocation.class);
         printLocations(location.getCountries());
    }

    public static void printLocations(List<GeneralLocation> locations) {       
        for (GeneralLocation son:locations) {
            System.out.println(son.getType()+": "+son.getName());
            printLocations(son.getSons());
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to add a root element to your xml to make it valid. For the input

```
<root>
    <Country name="USA">
        <City name="NewYork">
            <Street name="Something" />
            <Street name="Something2" />
        </City>
        <City name="LosAngeles">
            <Street name="Something" />
            <Street name="Something2" />
        </City>
    </Country>
</root>
```

The program prints out:

```
Country: USA
City: NewYork
Street: Something
Street: Something2
City: LosAngeles
Street: Something
Street: Something2
```

I know this is not the JAXB solution you were asking for, but it's shorter and it works.